# Time rescaling in overdamped Langevin simulation

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, dimensional-analysis

I'm simulating a system according to the Langevin equation (with inertia), however my friction coefficient is high enough that I am essentially in the overdamped regime on the timescales of one timestep. I also want the results of a simulation of the same system, but with a higher friction coefficient. I realized that because I am in the overdamped regime, without running a second simulation, I should get the dynamics if I rescale the time and velocities from my first simulation according to the same scale factor I want the friction coefficient to increase by. The scaling factor cancels out in both the overdamped Langevin equation and the Verlet algorithm I am using for my simulation, so it seems like this rescaling is legitimate.

However after rescaling, the effective time I have simulated for becomes longer. This seems too good to be true: what's to stop me from picking a lower friction coefficient (although high enough to still be in the overdamped regime) so that things happen faster, simulating for less time, then rescaling to match the actual parameters I want, without having to do the 'honest work' of simulating those actual parameters, which would take longer?

**Edit:**

I should have looked more carefully at my equations. The dimensionless overdamped Langevin equation for my system is:

$$x^*(\tau + \Delta\tau) = x^*(\tau) + \frac{\Delta\tau}{6\pi\eta^*R^*}F^*_{det} + \sqrt{\frac{2T^*\Delta\tau}{6\pi\eta^*R^*}}\xi(\tau)$$

therefore increasing $\Delta\tau$ and $\eta^*$ by the same factor will always cancel out (if I increase friction, I should be able to pick a larger timestep), therefore if I simulated using the overdamped equation, my rescaling would not help me gain any simulation time.

However, simulating with the Verlet algorithm, this is **not** the case. My simulation becomes unstable if I attempt to increase $\Delta \tau$ by the same factor  as $\eta^*$. The dimensionless equations are:

$$r_i^*(\tau+\Delta\tau) = r_i^*(\tau) + v_i^*(\tau)\Delta\tau + \frac{f_i^*(\tau)}{2m^*}\Delta\tau^2$$

$$v_i^*(\tau + \Delta\tau) = v_i^* + \frac{f_i^*(\tau+\Delta\tau) + f_i^*(\tau)}{2m^*}\Delta\tau$$

where $f_i^* = -\nabla U(\tau) - 6\pi \eta^*R^*v^*(\tau) + \sqrt{\frac{12\pi T^*\eta^*R^*}{\Delta \tau}}\xi(\tau)$

The force terms are problematic, because there the scaling does not cancel out, but I am in the overdamped regime on the timescales of each timestep, which I thought would mean these force terms would be very close to zero for me, but instead they are blowing up.

Comment: These are not Langevin equations. Did you perform any sanity check simulations with this method for cases with analytic solution? (such as diffusion in harmonic potential)

Comment: Sorry, I am always a bit confused by this terminology. I meant overdamped Langevin as it is sometimes called Brownian Dynamics (as by [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_dynamics). In the Verlet algorithm, my force is given by the equation of motion in Langevin dynamics (I have edited this, sorry it was not clear).

Comment: So did you simulate problems with known solutions to check your simulation?